Issue with Docker container size. NextJS deployment on ECR and ECS with Docker
I have a NextJS application, which is pretty light weight as it is used for my blogs. It is pretty static as it just displays a list of blogs and once you select one, it just shows you the details. The live site can be found at https://blogs.grocstock.com.au/.
The app is deployed ECS and I use a dockerfile to dockerize and push the image to ECS. The issue that I am facing is that the container size is 1.4GB (yes, gigabyte).
Here is my dockerfile
FROM node:20-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

COPY .env.production .env
COPY . .

RUN yarn build

FROM node:20-alpine as runner

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=builder /app/yarn.lock ./yarn.lock
COPY --from=builder /app/.env.production ./.env.production
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
RUN yarn install --production

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["yarn", "start"]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong in here and the actual app, which is built with Angular is 23Mb and the API built using NestJS is 185Mb.
How can I reduce the size of this image?
Any help is appreciated.
Updated the docker file as below to reduce the size to 250MB.
FROM node:20-alpine AS deps
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

FROM node:20-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .
COPY .env.production .env

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN yarn build

FROM node:20-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

COPY --from=builder /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./


EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["yarn", "start"]


I don't think you need node_modules in the final build. See this: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/deploying#docker-image , there is a link to an example: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker-multi-env/docker/production/Dockerfile

you use a multi-stage build, and copy over node_modules, negating all the benefits of a multi-stage build.

I removed COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules from the code, however the size hasn't gone done much, just 100MB

I updated the Docker file as following to reduce the size to 250MB. Updated the question.
